# Twitter "Tweet Share" Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am currently finishing up a simple random quote machine, you can see the code below. I'm having trouble integrating twitter's share button into my code. For some reason I cannot get it to pick up the text values from the quote that I have appearing and dynamically load it into a new window with the quote text attached. I've done a lot of research and couldn't find any clarification. I'm using some Jquery. If someone could assist me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Main File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Quote Machine</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Google Font -->

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnav" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         </div>

         <!-- the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainnav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
     </nav> <!-- /end Navbar -->

     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-offset-3 mainDiv">
              <div class="well">
                <h1> Random Inspirational Quotes </h1>
              </div>

              <div class="quoteDiv" id="quoteBox"></div>

              <div clas="authorDiv" id="authorBox"></div>

              <button class="btn btn-primary quoteButton" id="quoteButton">New Quote!</button>
              <br />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-offset-3 tweetButton">
              <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text="quotes.quote">Tweet</a>


            </div>
          </div>
     </div>


 <script>
    // Twitter Javascript -
         window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            t = window.twttr || {};
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

          t._e = [];
          t.ready = function(f) {
            t._e.push(f);
          };

          return t;
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

    </script>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Quotes -->
    <script src="js/quotes.js"></script>
    <!-- Main Logic -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One", serif; }
  body h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px; }
  body .quoteButton {
    text-align: center; }
  body .mainDiv {
    text-align: center; }
  body .authorDiv {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    border: 1px solid red; }
  body .quoteDiv {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; }
  body .tweet {
    padding-top: 10px; }
  body .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top; }
  body .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center; }
  body .tweetButton {
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center; }
```

Quotes.js (Where I am storing my quotes)

```
var quotes = [
    {author: "Bill Gates", quote: '"Success is a lousy teacher.  It seduces smart people into thinking they can’t lose."'},
    {author: "Larry Page", quote:'"If you’re changing the world, you’re working on important things. You’re excited to get up in the morning."'},
    {author: "Warren Buffet", quote:'"It’s better to hang out with people better than you. Pick out associates whose behavior is better than yours, and you’ll drift in that direction. "'},
    {author: "Phil Knight", quote:'"There is an immutable conflict at work in life and in business, a constant battle between peace and chaos. Neither can be mastered, but both can be influenced. How you go about that is the key to success."'},
    {author: "Carl Ichan", quote: '"I enjoy the hunt much more than the “good life” after the victory."'},
    {author: "Jeff Bezos", quote: '"I think frugality drives innovation, just like other constraints do. One of the only ways to get out of a tight box is to invent your way out."'},
    {author: "Mark Zuckerberg", quote: '"The biggest risk is not taking any risk…. In a world that’s changing really quickly, the only strategy that is guaranteed to fail is not taking risks. "'},
    {author: "Steve Ballmer", quote: '"Great companies, in the way they work, start with great leaders."'},
    {author: "Larry Ellison", quote: '"I have had all of the disadvantages required for success."'},
    {author: "Guy Kawasaki", quote: '"Ideas are easy. Implementation is hard."'},
    {author: "Henry Ford", quote: '"When everything seems to be going against you, remember that the airplane takes off against the wind, not with it."'}




];
```

App.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    console.log('ready!');  








        $('#quoteButton').click(function randomQuote() {

            newQuote = quotes[ranNum()]

        $('#quoteBox').hide().text(newQuote.quote).fadeIn('slow');
        $('#authorBox').text(newQuote.author);

            twttr.widgets.createShareButton(' ', document.getElementbyID('quoteBox'), {text: newQuote});

        });


        function ranNum() {

            return Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        }


        function generateTweet(text) {
            var tweetbutton = document.createElement('a');
            tweetButton.setAttribute('href', 'https://twitter.com/share');
            tweetButton.setAttribute('class', 'twitter-share-button');
            tweetButton.setAttribute('data-count', 'horizontal');
            tweetButton.setAttribute('data-text', text);

            return tweetButton;

        }





});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line here you have a typo. The function is `getElementById` (note the lowercase 'd').

```
 twttr.widgets.createShareButton(' ', document.getElementbyID('quoteBox'), {text: newQuote});
```

Even so, after changing it to lowercase I was still getting `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function`. Once I deleted this bit of code and rewrote it, the error disappeared so I suspect there is a formatting issue with one or more characters.

Additionally to display the text in the box, you'll need to access a property of the `newQuote` object i.e. `{text: newQuote.quote}`.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what I need to look into in order to fix this issue? You mentioned you rewrote some "code" - is that where my issue lies? I'm just trying to wrap my head around this fundamentally...

Comment: You have this code `document.getElementByID('quoteBox')`. This should use a lowercase "d" in `getElementById`. 

When I said that I rewrote the code, I meant that I deleted `document.getElementByID('quoteBox')` from the editor and wrote it out again as there seem to be some formatting issues.

Comment: I figured it out. I just used a custom made button. The twitter share button, I found was a bit difficult to implement. Thanks for your help!